# Counting unique entries in access

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I'm writing queries in access. I'm having problems with one where I want to count with distinct, but I have found out that it's not supported in access. I have looked at examples with sub queries but I don't get it and can't get it to work. Here is my original query:

```
SELECT Stad,COUNT(DISTINCT Biografer.BiograferID) AS Biografer ,COUNT(SalongsID) AS Salonger
FROM Biograf,Salong
WHERE Salong.BiografID=Biograf.BiografID
GROUP BY Stad
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's 5 parts study on the subject here: http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/search/label/Count%20Distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should learn proper `join` syntax.  Second, you can do this with nested subqueries:

```
SELECT Stad, COUNT(*) as NumBiorafer, SUM(Salonger) as SumSalonger
FROM (SELECT Stad, Biografer.BiograferID, COUNT(*) AS Salonger
      FROM Biograf INNER JOIN
           Salong
           ON Salong.BiografID = Biograf.BiografID
      GROUP BY Stad, Biografer.BiograferID
     ) as sb
GROUP BY Stad;
```